# Is this.someFunction.bind(this) redundant?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading someone's code and I see the following:

`this.device_name.changes().onValue(this.changeName.bind(this))`

From what I understand, `onValue` takes a callback function, and that function is `this.changeName.bind(this))`. Correct me if I'm wrong:

- The default value of `this` in a function call refers the object with which the function was called upon.
- The `.bind(someObject)` method causes the function's `this` to refer to `someObject` instead, when the function gets executed.

Knowing this (heh), `this.changeName.bind(this)` seems redundant: the default value for `this` when calling `this.changeName` will be the same `this` that is passed in the `bind` parameter.

So! Can the function be safely refactored to simply `this.changeName` with no differences in behavior?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: No, it's not, unless `changeName` doesn't use `this`. Why can't you just check it for yourself? )

Comment: The project is very large and I don't where this particular line gets executed. It was something I encountered at a glance.

Comment: Try it yourself: `var f = this.someMethod; f();` Note that this is different from just `this.someMethod();`

Comment: if the function doesn't use `this`, then it's fine to skip bind, ex:`fetch("/").then(Math.max).then(alert)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the bind is very important here.

A function's `this` pointer is set at the time the function is called. The call, in this case, is down inside whatever object is invoking the callback. Many objects just call with a this pointer either as null or (in the case of DOM objects) pointing to the DOM object itself.

Using the bind function this way returns a new function that hard-wired the `this` reference to the value passed to bind. If you take out the bind, it'll completely hose up the `this` pointer. It will DEFINITELY change the behavior.

Comment: Ah, I'm starting to understand now. Suppose `onValue` looks like `function (callback) { ... callback() }`. When `callback()` runs, what is it's default `this` value (the value without `bind`)?

Comment: There's one [very useful question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) (and an answer to it, of course).

Comment: Since the call is `callback()`, not `someObject.callback()`, the `this` would be null. Or maybe undefined, I'm not sure off the top of my head. But definitely not anything useful.